# Why is $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}\frac{x \sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+1}} - x = \frac12$?

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics, rational-functions

I need to evaluate this limit:
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{x \sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+1}}-x$$ to calculate the asymptote of this function:
$$\frac{x \sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+1}}$$
which, according to the class notes: $y=x+\frac{1}{2}$
with $a = 1$, $b = \frac{1}{2}$
However, the online math calculators say that currently no steps are available to show for this kind of problem.

I calculated this limit as $x\times \sqrt{1}-x = 1$, but apparently the correct answer is $\frac{1}{2}$.

What is my mistake?

Comment: See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). That may help to make your question more readable. As it stands right now, it is a mess.

Comment: You should start with stating which limit you are trying to find. $x\to\infty$, $x\to 0$, $x\to x_0$, or something else entirely. Otherwise it difficult to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: By the way, the answers currently fail to point out your mistake: you have $x\times f(x) - x$, where $f(x) \to 1$. You somehow "calculate" this as  $x\times \sqrt{1}-x=1$ (how?), but this is incorrect. More precisely, you can rewrite $$xf(x)-x = x(f(x)-1) "\to" \infty\cdot 0$$so you have an indeterminate form... and you need to get into more details about *how* $f(x)$ approaches its limit when $x\to \infty$ to conclude. (It turns out that when $x$ is big, $f(x) - 1 \simeq \frac{1}{2x}$, hence the limit...) *[Added to my answer, as comments are not meant to last.]*

Comment: hi
Thx for all the improvements in the question and the answers. I did not expect someone to answer actually, so I didn't spent a whole lot of time posing the question. My bad. As the question is the calculate a sledged straight asymptote (y=ax+b) to f(x) I guess the limit is for x to + or - infinity indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}{{x\sqrt{x+2}\over {\sqrt{x+1}}}}-x
&=\frac{x\sqrt{x+2}-x\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x+1}}\\
&=\frac{x\sqrt{x+2}-x\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x+1}}\left({{{x\sqrt{x+2}+x\sqrt{x+1}}\over {x\sqrt{x+2}+x\sqrt{x+1}}}}\right)\\
&={x\over{\sqrt{x+1}(\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x+1})}}\\
&={1\over{\sqrt{1/x+1}(\sqrt{1+2/x}+\sqrt{1/x+1})}}
\end{align}$$

so the limit at $+\infty$ is $1/2$.

Comment: I took the liberty to improve the formatting of your answer. Let me know if this looks fine to you.

Comment: it is ok with   me

Comment: I don't understand the last step. It seems you divided both num and denum by x, but 1/x under the square root, it should become 1/x^2, no? Also, when doing (a*b)/c, the c should only applied to a or b, not to both a and b. Here a = sqrt(x+1) and b = sqrt(x+2)+sqrt(x+1).

Comment: @TsemoAristide Thx. The only thing I still don't get from this is how to derive that sqrt(x+1) = sqrt(x*(x+(1/x))). It seems to me that it should be sqrt(x*(1+(1/x)))? You did it like that at the right side , but not at the left side of the denominator. But I guess it's a typo, because in your final solution above it is correct.

Comment: Yes it is a typo

Comment: $=x({1\over{\sqrt{x(1+1/x)}(\sqrt{x(1+2/x)}+\sqrt{x(1+1/x)}}})$

$=x({1\over{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{(1+1/x)}\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{(1+2/x)}+\sqrt{(1+1/x)}}})$

$=({1\over{\sqrt{(1+1/x)}(\sqrt{(1+2/x)}+\sqrt{(1+1/x)}}})$

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple approach. First of all sum the two fractions:
$$L := \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{x\sqrt{x + 2}}{\sqrt{x+1}} - x = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{x\sqrt{x + 2} - x\sqrt{x + 1}}{\sqrt{x + 1}}$$

With square roots it's usually the best to multiply and divide by the conjugate (in order to avoid indeterminate forms altogether):
$$L = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{x(\sqrt{x + 2} - \sqrt{x + 1})}{\sqrt{x+1}} = \lim_{x \to +\infty} x\frac{\sqrt{x + 2} - \sqrt{x + 1}}{\sqrt{x + 1}}\frac{\sqrt{x + 2} + \sqrt{x + 1}}{\sqrt{x + 2} + \sqrt{x + 1}}$$
Then:
$$\require{cancel}L = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\bcancel{\color{red}x}(\cancel{\color{green}x} + 2 - \cancel{\color{green}x} - 1)}{\bcancel{\color{red}x}\underbrace{\sqrt{1 + \frac1x}}_{\to 1}\underbrace{\left(\sqrt{1 + \frac2x} + \sqrt{1 + \frac1x}\right)}_{\to 2}} = \frac12$$

Answer (score 1):

*I assume the limit is for $x\to\infty$. (And yes, you **should** specify that sort of things... $x\to0$ would equally make sense!)*

Are you familiar with [Taylor expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions)? If so,$^{(\dagger)}$ essentially what you want is immediately implied by the following: for $x>0$,
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+1}} &= \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}}
= \frac{1+\frac{2}{2x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{1+\frac{1}{2x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}
= ({1+\frac{1}{x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)})({1-\frac{1}{2x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)})\\
&= {1+\frac{1}{2x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}
\end{align}$$
when $x\to\infty$, using Taylor expansions at $0$ (since $\frac{1}{x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} 0$).

It follows that
$$
x\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+1}} - 1\right)
= x\left(\frac{1}{2x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)
= \frac{1}{2}+o\left(1\right)\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} \frac{1}{2}
$$

---

*$(\dagger)$ If not, I strongly encourage you to look into these when you feel you have enough background. They form a powerful, versatile, systematic tool to compute limits, asymptotics, and estimates. Pretty much a Swiss army knife, only with Landau notations instead of a corkscrew.*

---

**Adding more on your specific mistake.** You have $x\cdot f(x) - x$, where $f(x) \to 1$ (here, I write $f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+1}}$ for convenience). You somehow "calculate" this as  $x\cdot \sqrt{1}-x=1$ (how?), but this is incorrect. More precisely, you can rewrite $$xf(x)-x = x(f(x)-1) "\to" \infty\cdot 0$$so you have an indeterminate form... and you need to get into more details about *how* $f(x)$ approaches its limit when $x\to \infty$ to conclude. (It turns out that when $x$ is big, $f(x) - 1 \simeq \frac{1}{2x}$, hence the limit...)

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I don't need to know the Taylor expansion thing for the classes for now.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$\frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+1}}=\sqrt{1+\frac1{x+1}}\approx\sqrt{1+2\cdot\frac1{2(x+1)}+\left(\frac1{2(x+1)}\right)^2}=1+\frac1{2(x+1)} $$
(of course you have to be more explicit about the "$\approx$" in your work)